# How to easily create a parser for custom formatted data in Python

Tags: python, parsing

The formatted data in file is similar to [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) and would like to create a grammer and parser for it. What is the easies way to do this in Python? Is there a tool that let you define a grammer for your data and parses according to the grammer?

P.S. I know the easier way to do this might be to change the data formate into JSON or other type but right now it can't be changed

Comment: [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) is a common answer.

Answer (score 3):

Look into pyparsing. It's a pretty simple library, but it is also quite powerful.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [PLY](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ply/3.4) in conjunction with [easyply](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/easyply/1.1) earlier, and liked it - maybe, you will find it neat to use with your custom format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd find [funcparselib](https://github.com/vlasovskikh/funcparserlib) worthy. It has easy syntax both for tokenization and syntax definitions.

[PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) is probably slower, but powerful and well-known.