# convert string to dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

How do i convert a string to python dictionary? I get the string in the following format as input from different application.

```
{ foo1 = [ "User1", "User2" ] bar1 = [ "User3", "User4" ] }
{ foo2 = [ "User5", "User6" ] }
{ foo3 = ["User7", "User8"] bar2 = [ "User9", "User10", "User 11" ] moo = ["User12"] }
```

I have to convert to the following format in python dictionary.

```
{ "foo1" : "User1,User2" , "bar1" : "User3,User4" }
{ "foo2" : "User5,User6" }
{ "foo3" : "User7" , "bar2" : "User9,User10,User 11" , "moo" : "User12"}
```

Comment: Can you fix the output of that different application so it would use a well-supported text-based serialization format (e.g. JSON, YAML) as it's output instead of it's own, home-cooked one?

Comment: Also - the use of comma as a separator doesn't seem consistent between 1st and 3rd example... What's going on there?

Comment: And `bar2` really gets scrunched into one string that's comma separated? Seems odd...

Comment: ya there are no commas in between keys. Just fixed that.

Comment: corrected the mistakes

Comment: Are you sure that the example output is actually what you want and that's the actual input? We've managed to change it a couple of times in a matter of minutes... it'd be a waste of time for someone to help answer this if it's liable to change again...

Comment: I corrected the dictionary again, my bad.  I want the array of users to be concatenated with single value in the output. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a third-party application that appears to be supplying you the data in a custom format, and does not support JSON or YAML or anything else conventional.

If that format is indeed completely custom without any serializers/deserializers already available, you have no choice but to write your own parser.

Thus your question becomes “[How to easily create a parser for custom formatted data in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000649/how-to-easily-create-a-parser-for-custom-formatted-data-in-python)?”